# "VIDEOJS: WARN: Player "media" is already initialized" when it is not

Tags: jquery, video.js

I currently experience a small issue where I receive a warning from video.js which is as following:

```
VIDEOJS: WARN: Player "media" is already initialized. Options will not be applied.
```

The bizarre thing is that it has not been initialized. But rather it is within a jQuery's `$(document).ready`.

The relevant code is:

```
<script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/5.19.1/video.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var player = videojs('media', {
            fluid: true,
            playbackRates: [0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2]
        });
    });
<script>
```

It know it has something to do with when how fast these resources get loaded, because every now and then the warning will not appear and the options are applied.

I do need this the player initialized once the "document is ready", though. How can I go about this issue?

Any help I would greatly appreciate!

Comment: Probably your video element has `class="video-js"` so the player gets initialized automatically before you do it manually.

Comment: Same problem here. `video = videojs('videoplayer', options);` gets just ignored. But how to properly initiliaze videojs without the css `class="video-js"` then? The main tutorial only explains the default css/js setup: http://docs.videojs.com/docs/guides/setup.html -- Update: Found it: Remove the `data-setup` attribute from the `video` tag in the html. Now the warning is gone and setup works.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. Videojs gets automatically initialized when the `data-setup` attribute is present in the `<video>` tag.

Remove `data-setup` and the player will not initialize by itself, the warning will not show up anymore when you execute the JS code now:

```
var player = videojs('media', options);
```

Now you can define the options and simply do ("media" is the id of your videoplayer):

```
var options = {
    "playbackRates": [1, 1.5, 2],
};

var video = videojs('media', options);

video.ready(function() {
    // …
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I also face the same problem. Videojs gets automatically initialized

Just Remove "data-setup" and the player will not initialize by itself

[image: remove data-setup]

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0):

use this code after `mounted()` in vue

```js
beforeDestroy() {
    if (this.player) {
        this.player.dispose()
    }
}
```